# Finding conditional Gaussian Mixture Model using scikit-learn.mixture.GMM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, normal-distribution

I'm using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.htm) to fit a multivariate Gaussian Mixture Model to some data (which works brilliantly). But I need to be able to get a new GMM conditional on *some* of the variables, and the scikit toolkit doesn't seem to be able to do that, which surprised me because it seems like a pretty basic thing to want to do.

Wikipedia [has a good explanation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) of what I'm trying to do (for a single Gaussian, not a GMM), and it's just possible I might be able to implement it myself, but my matrix maths isn't great and I can see it taking a long time.

Has somebody already done this? Is there an easy way of doing it with NumPy/SciPy/Scikit-learn?

Comment: Slice your data tensor along the relevant axes.

Comment: @SlaterTyranus  I _think_ you're suggesting that I fit a GMM to a sliced version of my dataset. I want to get a conditional GMM from the GMM I've already fitted to the full dataset.

Comment: @TomG Hi Tom, did you manage to find a solution to your question? The accepted answer doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try looking into [pypr](http://pypr.sourceforge.net/mog.html). From the documentation, here is how you would find a GMM conditioned on one or more of the variables:

```
# Now we will find the conditional distribution of x given y
(con_cen, con_cov, new_p_k) = gmm.cond_dist(np.array([np.nan, y]), \
    cen_lst, cov_lst, p_k)
```

As far as i remember, there are examples that come with the package.

Comment: I was nervous about using code described as "in its early stages" and which hasn't been updated for 4 years, but I gave it a try. Sadly the em_gm.py example (with the conditional GMM) doesn't work - the author seems to have used the keyword "iter" as a variable name in the definition of gmm.em_gm, which makes it crash.

Comment: In the example given in the documents, set "max_iter = 400" instead of "iter = 400" and "iter_call = None". If you want to track the progress of your EM algorithm, you can modify the plot function.

Comment: Thanks! That and a few other problems (like the fact that some documented features are only in the SVN, not in the latest download), and I've got it working!

Comment: Sorry, I'm a noob on here - I had to look up how to accept an answer.